# PHP regex non-capture non-match group

Tags: php, regex, date, preg-match, match

I'm making a date matching regex, and it's all going pretty well, I've got this so far:

```
"/(?:[0-3])?[0-9]-(?:[0-1])?[0-9]-(?:20)[0-1][0-9]/"
```

It will (hopefully) match single or double digit days and months, and double or quadruple digit years in the 21st century.  A few trials and errors have gotten me this far.

But, I've got two simple questions regarding these results:

1. `(?: )` what is a simple explanation for this?  Apparently it's a non-matching group.  But then...
2. What is the trailing `?` for?  e.g. `(? )?`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Edited (again) to improve formatting and fix the intro.]

This is a comment and an answer.

The answer part... I do agree with alex' earlier answer.

1. `(?: )`, in contrast to `( )`, is used to avoid capturing text, generally so as to have fewer back references thrown in with those you do want or to improve speed performance.
2. The ? following the `(?: )` -- or when following anything except `* + ?` or `{}` -- means that the preceding item may or may not be found within a legitimate match. Eg, `/z34?/` will match z3 as well as z34 but it won't match z35 or z etc.

The comment part... I made what might considered to be improvements to the regex you were working on:

```
(?:^|\s)(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30|31)-(0?[1-9]|10|11|12)-((?:20)?[0-9][0-9])(?:\s|$)
```

-- First, it avoids things like 0-0-2011

-- Second, it avoids things like 233443-4-201154564

-- Third, it includes things like 1-1-2022

-- Forth, it includes things like 1-1-11

-- Fifth, it avoids things like 34-4-11

-- Sixth, it allows you to capture the day, month, and year so you can refer to these more easily in code.. code that would, for example, do a further check (is the second captured group 2 and is either the first captured group 29 and this a leap year or else the first captured group is <29) in order to see if a feb 29 date qualified or not.

Finally, note that you'll still get dates that won't exist, eg, 31-6-11. If you want to avoid these, then try:

```
(?:^|\s)(?:(?:(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30|31)-(0?[13578]|10|12))|(?:(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)-(0?[469]|11))|(?:(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])-(0?2)))-((?:20)?[0-9][0-9])(?:\s|$)
```

Also, I assumed the dates would be preceded and followed by a space (or beg/end of line), but you may want ot adjust that (eg, to allow punctuations).

A commenter elsewhere referenced this resource which you might find useful:
http://rubular.com/

Comment: Great, very thorough and helpful in the first part.  I'm currently using `/[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-1]?[0-9]-(?:20)?[0-1][0-9]/` then running a `checkdate()` on the components to take care of fake dates.

Answer (score 8):

1. It is a non capturing group. You can not back reference it. Usually used to declutter backreferences and/or increase performance.
2. It means the previous capturing group is optional.

Comment: Groovy.  For future users here's a semi-helpful further explanation: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Answer (score 3):

**Subpatterns**

Subpatterns are delimited by parentheses (round brackets), which can be nested. Marking part of a pattern as a subpattern does two things:

1. It localizes a set of alternatives. For example, the pattern
   cat(aract|erpillar|) matches one of the words "cat", "cataract", or
   "caterpillar". Without the parentheses, it would match "cataract",
   "erpillar" or the empty string.
2. It sets up the subpattern as a capturing subpattern (as defined
   above). When the whole pattern matches, that portion of the subject
   string that matched the subpattern is passed back to the caller via
   the ovector argument of pcre_exec(). Opening parentheses are counted
   from left to right (starting from 1) to obtain the numbers of the
   capturing subpatterns.

For example, if the string "the red king" is matched against the pattern the ((red|white) (king|queen)) the captured substrings are "red king", "red", and "king", and are numbered 1, 2, and 3.

The fact that plain parentheses fulfill two functions is not always helpful. There are often times when a grouping subpattern is required without a capturing requirement. If an opening parenthesis is followed by "?:", the subpattern does not do any capturing, and is not counted when computing the number of any subsequent capturing subpatterns. For example, if the string "the white queen" is matched against the pattern the ((?:red|white) (king|queen)) the captured substrings are "white queen" and "queen", and are numbered 1 and 2. The maximum number of captured substrings is 65535. It may not be possible to compile such large patterns, however, depending on the configuration options of libpcre.

As a convenient shorthand, if any option settings are required at the start of a non-capturing subpattern, the option letters may appear between the "?" and the ":". Thus the two patterns

```
(?i:saturday|sunday)
(?:(?i)saturday|sunday)
```

match exactly the same set of strings. Because alternative branches are tried from left to right, and options are not reset until the end of the subpattern is reached, an option setting in one branch does affect subsequent branches, so the above patterns match "SUNDAY" as well as "Saturday".

It is possible to name a subpattern using the syntax (?Ppattern). This subpattern will then be indexed in the matches array by its normal numeric position and also by name. PHP 5.2.2 introduced two alternative syntaxes (?pattern) and (?'name'pattern).

Sometimes it is necessary to have multiple matching, but alternating subgroups in a regular expression. Normally, each of these would be given their own backreference number even though only one of them would ever possibly match. To overcome this, the (?| syntax allows having duplicate numbers. Consider the following regex matched against the string Sunday:

```
(?:(Sat)ur|(Sun))day
```

Here Sun is stored in backreference 2, while backreference 1 is empty. Matching yields Sat in backreference 1 while backreference 2 does not exist. Changing the pattern to use the (?| fixes this problem:

```
(?|(Sat)ur|(Sun))day
```

Using this pattern, both Sun and Sat would be stored in backreference 1.

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php